# RewriteRule in htaccess : I keep seeing the original URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been looking for answers here, but it seems like solutions that have worked for others are not solving it for me.

I want to rewrite my URLs so that they look better.

An example: 
Original URL: 
    `mywebsite.com/new/page.php?cat=web&view=thumbs`
Desired URL: 
    `mywebsite.com/new/web/thumbs`
(At the moment I'm developing this website in a subdirectory of my website, which I called 'new' .. I mention this because this might be the reason why things are not working, I don't know)

What I tried so far:

index.php:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <a href="<?php echo "page.php?cat=web&amp;view=thumbs";?>"><div id="web-btn" class="button"></div></a> 
        <a href="<?php echo "page.php?cat=illu&amp;view=thumbs";?>"><div id="illu-btn" class="button"></div></a>
        <a href="<?php echo "page.php?cat=info";?>"><div id="info-btn" class="button"></div></a>
        <a href="<?php echo "page.php?cat=anim&amp;view=thumbs";?>"><div id="anim-btn" class="button"></div></a>
        <a href="<?php echo "page.php?cat=brand&amp;view=thumbs";?>"><div id="brand-btn" class="button"></div></a>
    </div>

</body>
```

There are 2 variables in the href: 'cat' and 'view'. So in htaccess (located in root) I need these 2 variables to be fetched. I tried it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^new/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /new/page.php?cat=$1&view=$2 [L]
```

I get no error but the URLs are not rewritten, they still look like this: 
mywebsite.com/new/page.php?cat=web&view=thumbs

Same problem but slightly different:

A page with thumbnails that you can click on to get to a 'single' page is set up like this:

```
<div id="thumbs" class="medium-10 columns thumbs">
  <?php 
  $x = 1;

    while ($x <= 20){
      $item = ${'item'.$x.$cat};
      $txt = ${'txt'.$x.$cat};
      if(isset($item)) { echo '

      <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns" id="'.$item.'">
        <a href="page-content.php?cat='.$cat.'&amp;view=singles&amp;item='.$item.'&amp;txt='.$txt.'"><img src="'.$cat.'/thumbs/'.$item.'.jpg" /></a>
      </div>

    '; }

  $x++;
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

The hrefs here have 4 variables: 'cat', 'view', 'item' and 'txt'.

Right now the URLs look like this: 
    `mywebsite.com/new/page-content.php?cat=web&view=singles&item=webproject1&txt=blaaaa`

I want the URLs to be rewritten like this: 
    `mywebsite.com/new/web/webproject1`

I tried the following RewriteRule in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^new/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /new/page-content.php?cat=$1&view=singles&item=$2&txt=blaaaa [L]
```

Nothing happens with the URLs, but I get no errors.

The updated htaccess would be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^new/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /new/page.php?cat=$1&view=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^new/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /new/page-content.php?cat=$1&view=singles&item=$2&txt=blaaaa [L]
```

I can imagine something goes wrong because both RewriteRules start exactly the same (in both cases I need 2 variables divided by a / ), but on the other hand... it doesn't work either when I only use the first rule.

I have too little in-depth knowledge about htaccess and I'm stuck with troubleshooting so I really hope someone can give me some insight. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `.htaccess` will not convert URL to user-friendly. It's only for redirecting user-friendly url. So if you have link with `/new/page.php?car=5`, and click on it, you will be sent to this URL, not to `/new/page/5`.

Comment: Of course you need to put the “nice” URLs into your HTML links.

Comment: yes I thought so, but if I put the 'nice' URL in the href I get: Forbidden
You do not have permission to access this document.